# Adjust iTextSharp Text Extraction Newline Threshold

Tags: c#, .net, text, itext, extract

I am extracting text from pdfs with iTextSharp within particular rectangles.

```
RenderFilter renderfilter = new RegionTextRenderFilter(pdfRect);
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), renderfilter);
var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
```

Some of the lines have text which varies in its vertical alignment so that I'm getting newlines where there should not be newlines.
How can I override the newline detection to increase the threshold for which to treat the text as being on the same line? I have looked at the SameLine method but I don't see how I can use that even if I override the LocationTextExtractionStrategy or if it is even necessary to do so?

Comment: If the variation in vertical alignment is going strictly downwards, changing `SameLine` should suffice. I'm afraid, though, it would be easiest to copy the whole `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` and manipulate the copy because of many private members. If the variation can also be in the upwards direction, you will also have to replace the `filteredTextChunks.Sort()` call.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Can you give any more detail around it? So SameLine is called for each letter to tell if it's on the same line? And then what exactly would I have to change in the Sort call?

Comment: *SameLine is called for each letter to tell if it's on the same line* - No, for each chunk. But chunks may indeed consist of single letters (usually, though, th are longer).

Comment: *And then what exactly would I have to change in the Sort call* - The sort call sorts the chunks top to bottom, left to right. If you have vertical alignment variations going up, the tail of the line is sorted *before* its head. In that case you have to change that strict sorting into something that  ignores slight variations in the vertical alignment. And this can be really tricky, depending on how bad the variations are in comparison to the line height.

Comment: Yeh, I tried some modifications and failed. It mostly worked and then not on some other critical files. I'm going to try again from scratch. I'm open to any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I needed by implementing your suggestions. I'm using a "magic" value here, and it likely should be related to the glyph sizes. But for now this works for me. I could see parameterizing that "5" value if applying some heuristics.

```
virtual public int CompareTo(TextChunk rhs)
{
    if (this == rhs) return 0; // not really needed, but just in case

    int rslt = 0;
    rslt = CompareInts(orientationMagnitude, rhs.orientationMagnitude);
    if (rslt != 0 && AbsoluteDifference(orientationMagnitude, rhs.orientationMagnitude) > 5)
    return rslt;


    rslt = CompareInts(distPerpendicular, rhs.distPerpendicular);
    if (rslt != 0 && AbsoluteDifference(distPerpendicular, rhs.distPerpendicular) > 5)
    return rslt;

    // note: it's never safe to check floating point numbers for equality, and if two chunks
    // are truly right on top of each other, which one comes first or second just doesn't matter
    // so we arbitrarily choose this way.
    rslt = distParallelStart < rhs.distParallelStart ? -1 : 1;

    return rslt;
}

virtual public bool SameLine(TextChunk a)
{
    if (orientationMagnitude != a.orientationMagnitude && AbsoluteDifference(orientationMagnitude, a.orientationMagnitude) > 5) return false;
    if (distPerpendicular != a.distPerpendicular && AbsoluteDifference(distPerpendicular,a.distPerpendicular) > 5) return false;
    return true;
}

public int AbsoluteDifference(int num1, int num2)
{
    return Math.Abs(num1 - num2);
}
```

Comment: you can also modify code in             public virtual bool SameLine(ITextChunkLocation other) {
                return OrientationMagnitude == other.OrientationMagnitude &&
                       DistPerpendicular == other.DistPerpendicular;
            } , just changing the equal condition to a value of difference that meets your need.